# How to separately configure producer and consumer in spring boot rabbitmq?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am a newbie to Spring boot RabbitMQ. I would like to know how to separately configure producer and consumer, say if they are two separate entities(may be different hosts). I have sample code-

Sender.java

```
package ch.keko.springamqp;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class Sender {

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 500L)
public void send() {
    this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("foo", "test queue");
}

}
```

SampleAmqpSimpleApplication.java

```
package ch.keko.springamqp;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SampleAmqpSimpleApplication {

@Bean
public Sender mySender() {
    return new Sender();
}


@Bean
public Listerner myListener() {
    return new Listerner();
}

@Bean
public Queue fooQueue() {
    return new Queue("foo");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SampleAmqpSimpleApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Listener.java

```
package ch.keko.springamqp;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;

import java.util.Date;

@RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
public class Listerner {

@RabbitHandler
public void process(@Payload String foo) {
    System.out.println(new Date() + ": " + foo);
}
}
```

I would like to know what are the minimum necessary configurations needed if we are separating producer and consumer as two different independent entities.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you just need Producer/Consumer Classes for every Queue you are using. The Payload / Message is what is different in every Queue, never mix them up.

In RabbitMQ you could use Queues or Exchanges, lets say:
    com.megna.queue1.in
    com.megna.queue1.out

```
com.megna.queue2.in
com.megna.queue2.out

com.megna.queue3.in
com.megna.queue3.out
```

Basically com.megna.queueX is for your entities and in/out are for sending and receiving. But in and out could differ, because in could be an full object as XML and out is the answer Queue you just send an OK, and answer object or an Exception back. In my projects I have 3 objects for that:

```
QueueObjectData - The Object / Message / Payload I want to process
QueueObjectAnswer - The answer of an successful processing
QueueException - Generalized Exception Class with informationen, Stacktrace etc.
```

The Consumer queue3 subscribes to com.megna.queue3.in, deserializing (consuming) the entity queue3Data and sends back the answer queue3Answer or QueueException back via the producer who is configured for it, never by itself.

In production environments you will find different names for it, sometimes request for in and response for out. But they are all the same thing, exchanging messages over the MQ.

If you have a Frontend Cluster subscribing for answers from queue3.out to show the result to the user, keep in mind MQs is FIFO, so it is not that easy to send a message for an user back, you have to think about in the frontend or use way more queues, ie 3 frontend servers in cluster need 3 queues. But in reality this is even whorse because the user could change the server and the message could never get received by the user.

RabbitMQ has a way better system for that, instead of queues, use exchanges (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html) and subscribe to them. You could use the same system like above, but they are exchanges and send to multiple queues and subscribers. Downside is, if you cluster your backend with 2 or more machines, every Consumer in the backend gets the message.

Here you have to balance the whole thing out. You would not be the first one getting racing conditions by multiple Consumers doing the same thing.

MQ is not an easy thing, so configuring it is not just some lines of code, you must have a concept who is responsible and based on that, do you need an Queue or an Exchange. In the Tutorial above you get the example code, but still, you have to know what you are doing.